# Why data isn't deleting using jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, express

I want to delete data using jQuery ajax, but it's not working.
Can anyone please suggest why it's not working or where it is wrong

HTML code:

```
  <a href="" class="delete-evidance" class="btn btn-outline-danger my-2 my-sm-0">Delete</a>
```

jQuery code:

```
  $(".delete-evidance")({
url: "/goal/delete/evidance._id/data._id",
ajaxOptions: {
  dataType: "json"
},
success: (data, config) => {
  const res = data.responseJSON;
  $.bootstrapGrowl(
    `<h4>Successfully Deleted!</h4><p>${res.returnObject.msg}</p>`,
    {
      type: "warning",
      delay: 3500,
      allow_dismiss: true
    }
  );
  return `Error\n${res.returnObject.msg}`;
}
});
```

nodejs controller code(this code is just to know whats happening at backend):

```
  var evidanceDelete = function(req, res, next) {
   const updateObj = {
     $pull: {
      evidance: {
      _id: req.params.evidanceId
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi welcome to SO, can you please give us more to work on.

where is the data stored ? 
are you trying to delete a data stored in the backend ?

Comment: See, in your ajax url you are just passing a string but I think ideally these should be valid id's i.e. `evidance._id` and `data._id`.

Comment: @NijeeshJoshy yes the data is stored in backend

Comment: @NijeeshJoshy i hv updated the code chk the question again

Comment: @PraveenKr.Saini yes these are the valid ids check the question again

Comment: @alphadev, but your url is just a string. It doesn't contain any variables with the id.

Comment: @praveen-me  so plz tell what i have to do, may be the code is wrong for this reason i posted it here

Comment: @alphadev, According to me you need to make your url consisted of appropriate id's instead of strings.

Comment: @praveen-me how can i make url consisted of appropriate id's instead of strings, can u show code

Comment: Suppose, 
`evidance._id = 5` and `data._id = 8`, then you can compose your url like that.
```
`goal/delete/${evidance._id}/${data._id}`
```

Comment: @praveen-me thnx and i think something is missing here in brackets after class $(".delete-evidance")  some missing here  ({

Comment: Debug your server-side code, what parameters to do you get? Are they the expected ones?   are you even hitting the backend?  This code `$(".delete-evidance")({` is clearly wrong (there's an answer for this part already). `evidance._id/data._id` is passing as a string (as already commented) not the/an actual id, perhaps you meant `"/goal/delete/" + evidance._id + "/" + data._id` (or using the string interpolation as above).   Finally, it's "evidence" (off topic).

Comment: @freedomn-m the delete functionality was working fine its code was in ejs it just send to to raw json page on delete, for this reason i try to write some code in jquery ajax to show an alert and as below answer all is fine except url